# Push function does not work inside nested json call (from multiple APIs using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, getjson

I want to create an HTML table using multiple JSON APIs. These APIs are dependent on one another and hence I have to make nested getJSON calls for the same.

I have used nested getJSON calls. However, only the outer push works and the inner ones are not working. That is why only the city names show up in the table created.

**Slight edit in the code**:

```
var tr;
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("project.json", function(data){ 
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
            tr = [];
      tr.push('<tr>');
     $.each(value, function(key1, value1){
        $.getJSON("builder.json", function(data2){
        $.each(data2, function(key2, value2){
            if (key2 == key){
                //console.log(value2);
                 tr.push('<td>'+ (value2) +'</td>');
                 return;
            }
        });
      });
        tr.push('<td>'+ (value1.project) +'</td>');
        //console.log(value1.project);
        $.getJSON("city.json", function(data3){
        $.each(data3, function(key3, value3){
            if (key3 == value1.city){
                //console.log(value3);
                 tr.push('<td>'+ (value3) +'</td>');
                 return;
            }
        });
      });
        $.getJSON("price.json", function(data4){
        $.each(data4, function(key4, value4){
            if (key4 == value1.project_id){
                //console.log(value4);
                 tr.push('<td>'+ (value4) +'</td>');
                 return;
            }
        });
      });
     });
      tr.push('</tr>');
      $('#emp').append($(tr.join('')));
  });
 });
});
```

Table is as follows:

```
<table id="emp">
  <tr>
    <th>Builder</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
```

The APIs are given as:

builder.json

```
{
    "1":"alamiz builder",
    "2":"souroy builder",
    "3":"vin selv builder",
    "4":"gol mat builder",
    "5":"sm dev builder",
    "6":"zahi builder"
}
```

city.json

```
{
    "1":"mumbai",
    "2":"delhi",
    "3":"pune",
    "4":"banglore"
}
```

project.json

```
{
   "1":[
       {"project_id":1,"project":"Alamiz City","city":1},
       {"project_id":2,"project":"Alamiz Tech City","city":1},
       {"project_id":3,"project":"Alamiz Down Town","city":3},
       {"project_id":10,"project":"Alamiz Nature","city":2}
   ],
   "3":[
       {"project_id":4,"project":"The Tech Sky","city":1},
       {"project_id":5,"project":"Alphonso","city":1}
   ],
   "4":[
       {"project_id":6,"project":"Royal Tech","city":4},
       {"project_id":7,"project":"Future City","city":4}
   ],
   "6":[
       {"project_id":8,"project":"Zahi Skyline","city":1}
   ],
   "2":[
       {"project_id":9,"project":"Souras City","city":4}
   ]
}
```

price.json

```
{
   "1":"2cr",
   "2":"3.5cr",
   "3":"1cr",
   "4":"2cr",
   "5":"4cr",
   "6":"4cr",
   "7":"5cr",
   "8":"3cr",
   "9":"7cr",
   "10":"6cr"
}
```

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is an asynchronous request.  You are intermixing synchronous and asynchronous logic all over the place here.

Comment: I would suggest trying to implement [jQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), giving it all four of your `getJSON` calls, and then the `then()` of the `when()` will receive all the responses at the same time for you to process them as you desire.

Comment: Formatting the JSON API results would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Now what I do not understand is that only the cities are being added into the table. The table has the heads Builder-Project-City-Price. How do I insert all of them into the table?

Comment: @Taplar Can you edit this code and provide me a solution.

Answer (score -2):

$.each is asynchronous and when its run inside of a for loop, which is synchronous, the for loop finishes before any of the callbacks fire.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: `$.each` is absolutely not asynchronous